# Unable to build and run Unity application on HoloLens 2

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I'm trying to build my first HoloLens app using Unity. I imported the MRTK and its features. I also connected the HoloLens through USB. As soon as I press "Build and Run" it provides 3 errors. My build settings for Universal Windows Platform are the following:

- Target Device: HoloLens,
- Architect: ARM (I also tried ARM64),
- Build Type: D3D Project,
- Target SDK Version: Latest Installed,
- Minimum Platform Version: (all the versions give the same error),
- Visual Studio Version: Latest Installed,
- Build and Run on: USB Device,
- Build Configuration: Release.

Regardless of the build settings, the following errors appear as soon as I press the "Build and Run":

```
BuildFailedException: Deployment failed.
Output:[22:13:39.766] Windows Phone Player Runner started.
[22:13:39.772] Connecting to device.
[22:13:39.788] An error occurred while running: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop, Version=7.1.40304.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DatastoreManager..ctor(DatastoreConfiguration configuration)
   at Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DatastoreManager.Get(Int32 localeId)
   at Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.Wrapper.ConnectivityWrapper12.GetCurrentPlatform(Int32 localeId)
   at WindowsPhonePlayerRunner.Program.GetDevice()
   at WindowsPhonePlayerRunner.Program.Run(String appxPath, RunnerFlags runnerFlags, IEnumerable`1 copyFilesTo)
   at WindowsPhonePlayerRunner.Program.Main(String[] args)
[22:13:39.788] Exiting Windows Phone Player Runner.

ApplicationLauncherImpl.RunOnPhone (System.String commandLine)
ApplicationLauncherImpl.Run (Utility+VisualStudio vs)
ApplicationLauncher.BuildAndRunProject (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildLaunchPlayerArgs args, UnityEditor.WSABuildAndRunDeployTarget deployTarget, System.String platform, Utility+VisualStudio vs)  
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Launch (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget buildTarget, System.String path, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport buildReport) (at <55729f52d042492e9efc384182ae2feb>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 177 seconds (176835 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ca] in <55729f52d042492e9efc384182ae2feb>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <55729f52d042492e9efc384182ae2feb>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the build log, the "Windows Phone Player Runner" related output should be caused by two possible reasons:

1. Incorrect Unity version.
2. *Build and Run on: USB Device* setting

For Unity version, we recommend using the Unity 2020 LTS version for HoloLens 2 development: https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/lts-releases?version=2020.3

For **Build and Run on** setting, it the issue is caused by Build and Run on: USB Device setting, this is a known [issue](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/build-and-run-deployment-fails-on-hololens-that-is-attached-via-usb) and won't fix by Unity. The best practice is, please switch to **Local Machine** and generate the Visual Studio Project. With the help of Visual Studio, you can deploy to your HoloLens 2 via wireless network or USB cable. See:

- **Build and deploy the application** section in this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/learn-mrtk-tutorials/1-7-exercise-hand-interaction-with-objectmanipulator)
- [Using Visual Studio to deploy and debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-visual-studio?tabs=hl2)